# dgrid add new row on button click

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am trying to make an editable grid. I would like to provide users to be able to like more rows if needed. I tried going to their documentation yet it wasn't obvious.

Also, what does `grid.newRow()` do?

Answer (score 5):

If you're trying to add a new row, you can always just add a new entry to the underlying grid store first.

Say you have a grid (named "grid" of users), you can have your button do this:

```
var button = new Button({
    label: "Add User",
    onClick: function() {
        var user = {id: 1, name: "test"};
        grid.store.add(user);
    }
});
```

Also I don't believe the regular grids have a newRow option, only the onDemandGrid or onDemandList has a newRow option. But the above code should work for what you asked for.

Comment: `newRow` is defined in `List` but it is normally called automatically in reaction to observed store changes, so its application is generally limited to `OnDemandList` and `Pagination` (and anything else using `_StoreMixin`).  And to clarify, if you add items to an observable store backing the grid, you don't need to call `newRow` directly at all.

Comment: Have you had an issue with the table headers disappearing after adding a row like this?